# Codename One landscape oriented Form in a portrait locked app

Tags: codenameone

I have a Codename One app which orientation is locked to portrait. That app is build to Android and iOS. It's a social and the portrait orientation is fine, except for video and images when they are landscape oriented.

To see a full screen image in a landscape orientation, I workarounded the problem rotating the image before showing it. However I suppose that the same workaround is not applicable to play a video.

How can I programmatically change the orientation of a Form to landscape when the app is locked to portrait? Otherwise, how can I satisfy the use case that I described? Thank you

Comment: Maybe my use case is better described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59494044/custom-action-after-tapping-a-video-during-the-playback-or-when-the-playback-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works on Android and doesn't work for our iOS port. Notice that if you use the `setNativePlayerMode` it will work for iOS as well but you won't have any control as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59495797/756809

You can set orientation to landscape explicitly using `CN.lockOrientation(false)`. You can release the lock using `CN.unlockOrientation()`.

But this will only work on Android and won't really impact iOS.