# Custom action after tapping a video during the playback or when the playback ends

Tags: codenameone

My use case: I have an image that is the preview of a video. When the user tap the preview, the video should starts a fullscreen playback (I suppose in another Form). When the video ends or when the user tap the video during the playback, the previous Form should be shown. This is the same use case of the question: [Codename One landscape oriented Form in a portrait locked app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59493906/codename-one-landscape-oriented-form-in-a-portrait-locked-app)

My question: the `MediaPlayer` class doesn't seem to expose a method to perform a custom action when pressing the video or when the video ends, like requested by this use case. The `MediaPlayer` is a peer component, so I'm not sure if trying to use a button as a leader component can make sense to do an action after a tap. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately media is pretty complicated in that sense. You can either rely on the behavior of the media player natively which handles orientation change, playback etc. seamlessly (seek etc.). Or you can implement everything on your own in a media object in which case you can use native peer overlay and have a transparent component on top of the media view which will grab all the clicks.

The former will provide a more native UX and will auto-rotate the UI but we don't have control since there's no `Form` underlying the UI. It's shown when you invoke `setNativePlayerMode(true)`. When you tap the video in this case it pauses. To exit playback you would use device native keys e.g. back or a done button and would be returned to the parent `Form`. Notice that since this is native behavior it acts differently on the device and it's important to do device testing here.

Your alternative is to place a media component in the center of the screen and then you can override everything and customize everything. You can place a layered layout on top and grab all tap events. You will need to add your own progress, play, pause etc. UI elements. The user would need to physically rotate the device as orientation won't switch on its own (for the most part).